# Rounding is inconsistent after floating point math

Tags: c++, rounding-error

Take the following example (with contrived numbers):

```
double a = 9.0, b = 2.0;
double c = a / b;
int d = RoundAndCastToInt(c);
```

Across multiple runs, the value of `d` isn't consistent. Here are two contrived ways the math gets performed:

> **Execution 1:**
>
> 9.0 / 2.0 == 4.49999...
>
> RoundAndCastToInt(4.49999...) == 4
>
> **Execution 2:**
>
> 9.0 / 2.0 == 4.5
>
> RoundAndCastToInt(4.5) == 5

I want to get the same value consistently across different executions and different machines. In the example above, a result of either `4` or `5` is fine as long as it is *always* `4` or *always* `5`.

Comment: What's your inputs? What's your expected output? What does the Convert() functions do?

Comment: In the example code, the two variables a and b do not get initialised. Or, if they _do_ get initialised, can you please show the real code.

Comment: Does [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) help?

Comment: I've edited your question heavily because it seems that many users were confused. I've attempted to restate your problem in another way. If I'm mistaken about your problem or you dislike my changes, please revert it.

Comment: I honestly don't know why this got closed. The question contained desired/actual behavior even before I edited it. `Convert` was easily figured out from the context. I can't find a good answer for this either. As far as I can tell, this is a good question.

Comment: Thank you for restructure my question. Your understanding is right. The background is integration/regression test where we run two binaries built from different version of a repo. We get an unexpected diff due to such an issue.

Comment: @ubc_ben But without any concrete examples, this problem is not reproducible. The example in the edit only ever results in exactly 4.5, unless you can provide a situation where it does not.

Answer (score -1):

This might be stupid with a lot of unsolved details, but I guess it can work when you know the precision of the solution you want...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  float i = 5.3 / 4.7;
  float j = 5.3 / 4.7;

  printf("i %f \n", round(i * 10000.0) / 10000.0);
  printf("j %f \n", round(j * 10000.0) / 10000.0);


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh... you only need an integer. Then "round" is all you need... for c... for c++, I guess there std::round() is what you need, as others said.

Comment: This is C answer, not C++